# Reset Connection With RST Flag TCP

Tags: network, tcp, networking, network-theory

When a connection has been established between Host A and Host b, Then there is data exchange between host A and host b,Let's say host A already has 3 segments, segments 1 and 2 have been sent and received acknowledgment and then host B suddenly because maybe for some reason sends an rst Flag to reset the connection Then, when the connection is reset, does that mean host A will start from the beginning again, in this case the host A will send data from segment 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a RST is sent or received, the connection is finished. The sockets return to their CLOSED or LISTEN states. As far as the transport layer is concerned, there's no picking up again. Possibly, a new socket connection is created that's all new, without anything being carried over from the previous connection.

If your question refers to the application layer (off topic here on NE), then some clients may try using protocol options to pick off from where the session broke, e.g. with larger downloads in HTTP or FTP.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir